# How to update all values in column except the last occurrence for an ID

Tags: sql, hive, sql-update, hiveql

I have the following table `laundry`:

```
item | wash1 | wash2
abc1 | A     | B
abc1 | B     | C
abc1 | C     | D
abc2 | A     | E
abc2 | E     | F
```

where wash1 and wash2 are `dates`.
I want to decrease the wash2 date by one day for each item ID such that the wash2 date for the last occurrence stays the same for that ID.

```
item | wash1 | wash2
abc1 | A     | B-1
abc1 | B     | C-1
abc1 | C     | D
abc2 | A     | E-1
abc2 | E     | F
```

Comment: What is your DBMS ?

Comment: RDBMS; and using MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Hive:

```
insert overwrite table laundry
select 
     item, wash1, 
     case when rn=1 then wash2
          else date_sub(wash2,1) 
      end wash2
from
(
select item, wash1, wash2,
       row_number() over(partition by item order by wash2 desc) rn  --latest=1 
  from laundry
)s;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL DBMS,use like this simple code:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB("2017-06-15", INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Set your column in the part one, like:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(wash2, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
from laundry
Where wash2 <> MAX(wash2);
```

This function isn't work in the  SQL server

Comment: This would decrease all the dates. I want to decrease all except the last occurrence for the wash2 date for that ID

Comment: use where end of the query... check edited answer... I'm SQLSERVER DBA... use   <> or != for "where" command

Comment: Can I do it in two steps - step1 date_sub the entire column and step2 update the column by date_add of 1 day to max value of wash2 for that ID?

Comment: Yes, you can. Do you need two step codes? You can use tigger, for inserted data. Trigger can update your inserted entry data